# Реализация сортировки массива методом шейкера через функцию. Помогите найти ошибки

Tags: c++, c, массивы, функции, указатели

Задано массив чисел(матрица). Надо отсортировать методом Шейкера через функцию.

```
void sortSalary(int** Salary, int amountGroup, int amountYears)

{
    int temp = 0, min = *(*(Salary)), max = *(*(Salary)), min_i = 0, min_j = 0, max_i = 0, max_j = 0;
    int left_i = 0, left_j = 0, right_i = amountGroup, right_j = amountYears;
    for (int k = 0; k < (amountGroup * amountYears) / 2; k++)
    {
        //Поиск минимального 
        for (int i = left_i; i < right_i; i++)
        {
            for (int j = left_j; j < right_j; j++)
            {
                if (*(*(Salary + i) + j) < min)
                {
                    min = *(*(Salary + i) + j);
                    min_i = i;
                    min_j = j;
                }
            }
        }
        if (left_j != amountYears)
        {
            temp = *(*(Salary + left_i) + left_j);
            *(*(Salary + left_i) + left_j) = min;
            *(*(Salary + min_i) + min_j) = temp;
            left_j++;
        }
        else
        {
            left_j = 0;
            left_i++;
            temp = *(*(Salary + left_i) + left_j);
            *(*(Salary + left_i) + left_j) = min;
            *(*(Salary + min_i) + min_j) = temp;
        }
        min = max;
        //Поиск максимального
        for (int i = left_i; i < right_i; i++)
        {
            for (int j = left_j; j < right_j; j++)
            {
                if (*(*(Salary + i) + j) > max)
                {
                    max = *(*(Salary + i) + j);
                    max_i = i;
                    max_j = j;
                }
            }
        }
        if (right_j != 1)
        {
            temp = *(*(Salary + (right_i - 1)) + (right_j - 1));
            *(*(Salary + (right_i - 1)) + (right_j - 1)) = max;
            *(*(Salary + max_i) + max_j) = temp;
            right_j--;
        }
        else
        {
            right_j = amountYears;
            right_i--;
            temp = *(*(Salary + (right_i - 1)) + (right_j - 1));
            *(*(Salary + (right_i - 1)) + (right_j - 1)) = max;
            *(*(Salary + max_i) + max_j) = temp;
        }
        temp = *(*(Salary + (right_i - 1)) + (right_j - 1));
        *(*(Salary + (right_i - 1)) + (right_j - 1)) = max;
        *(*(Salary + max_i) + max_j) = temp;
        max = min;
    }
}
```

Comment: Где описания задания/структур данных? Что такое `Salary`? Двумерный массив? Почему это двумерный массив?

Comment: Я написал в теме что это массив, Salary двойной указатель на этот масив (я знаю что это не 2 указатель так проще сказать)

Comment: Еще раз повторяю вопрос: Вы в коде работаете с `Salary` как с **двумерным** массивом. Откуда взялся двумерный массив? Почему двумерный?

Comment: Всм почему двумерный. Такое задание. Он задан по условию задания. Его надо отсортировать методом Шейкера передав в функцию.

Comment: Прекрасно.Так в чем проблема? В чем проявляются "ошибки"? (Ваш код было бы в 100 раз проще читать, если бы вместо инопланетянского `*(*(Salary + left_i) + left_j)` вы писали просто человеческое `Salary[left_i][left_j]`)

Comment: Проблема в том что это функция которую я вызываю в main()

Comment: Ну так не делайте этого.

Comment: У меня задание сделать так. Прочитайте тему а потом пишите.

Comment: Прочитайте-ка вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking, а потом пишите.